# Function equivalent to (python) seaborn's "set_context()" in (R) ggplot2?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, tidyverse

A quite neat function of python's library `seaborn` is to be able to all the sizes of the plots, labels and the majority of graph elements with a single command: [`set_context(context)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html), for different contexts the sizes of figures are resized accordingly, so if context is `talk` everything is larger, but for `paper` they are scaled down so there is space to include more information in a single graph.

Is there a function equivalent to `set_context()` in `ggplot2`?

currently, I am using many `theme` instructions, such as:

```
...
theme(text = element_text(size=14)) +
...
```

and hardcoding all the sizes in the code

Comment: take a look here: https://statisticsglobe.com/ggthemes-package-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `seaborn`, but based on your description I think there are two features in {ggplot2} that might suit your needs.

If you want all your plots to use the same theme, you can run `theme_set()` at the top of your script/document to use the same theme for all your plots. Here you can declare a specific ["complete theme"](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) and then use `base_size` to set a default font size. So I often use `theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 16))` at the top of many of my scripts to avoid retyping that for each plot.

If you want to apply different complex themes to different plots, you can just save each theme to a variable and call it as needed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# create custom themes and assign to variable
theme_talk <- theme(text = element_text(size = 14))
theme_paper <- theme(text = element_text(size = 8))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()

# call custom themes as needed
p + ggtitle("Talk theme has big text") + theme_talk
```

[image]

```r
p + ggtitle("Paper theme has small text") + theme_paper
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>